# JSON object converter to interactive html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, node.js

I am working in Node.JS and dealing with large JSON objects that look like this (when formatted mind you)

```
    {
   "_id": "552ecae96054158575914f50",
   "Wpt-1": {
      "Lat": "34.843213",
      "Lon": "-118.005453",
      "Alt": 5000,
      "Ty": 4,
      "Scale-Lat": 6,
      "Scale-Lon": 6,
      "Scale-Alt": 4,
      "Tu": 1,
      "Vel": 132
   },
   "Wpt-2": {
      "Lat": "34.852209",
      "Lon": "-117.987876",
      "Alt": 4500,
      "Ty": 5,
      "Scale-Lat": 6,
      "Scale-Lon": 6,
      "Scale-Alt": 4,
      "Tu": 1,
      "Vel": 132
   },
   "Pri-Wpt": {
      "Lat": "34.89528",
      "Lon": "-117.903598",
      "Alt": 2100,
      "Ty": 5,
      "Scale-Lat": 6,
      "Scale-Lon": 6,
      "Scale-Alt": 4,
      "Tu": 0,
      "Vel": 127
   },
   "Wpt-4": {
      "Lat": "34.904633",
      "Lon": "-117.885272",
      "Alt": 2100,
      "Ty": 2,
      "Scale-Lat": 6,
      "Scale-Lon": 6,
      "Scale-Alt": 4,
      "Tu": 0,
      "Vel": 6
   },
   "Details": {
      "187674": {
         "3344800": [
            {
               "Geo-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": 242,
                  "Pri-Wpt-Indx": 21,
                  "Validation-Status": "Validated",
                  "Geo-Res": 67,
                  "Taxi-Only-Route": false
               }
            },
            {
               "Ctg-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": {
                     "c4_route": 187761,
                     "c4_indx": 1,
                     "c4_rwy": "Edw Rwy 04R (500ft)",
                     "c4_routeNum": 92,
                     "c4_wptNum": 584
                  },
                  "Hash": -1807266671
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "188465": {
         "3361007": [
            {
               "Geo-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": 1966,
                  "Pri-Wpt-Indx": 31,
                  "Validation-Status": "Validated",
                  "Geo-Res": 67,
                  "Taxi-Only-Route": false
               }
            },
            {
               "Ctg-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": {
                     "c4_route": 187761,
                     "c4_indx": 1,
                     "c4_rwy": "Edw Rwy 04R (500ft)",
                     "c4_routeNum": 95,
                     "c4_wptNum": 942
                  },
                  "Hash": -1807266671
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "202129": {
         "3653337": [
            {
               "Geo-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": 504,
                  "Pri-Wpt-Indx": 21,
                  "Validation-Status": "Validated",
                  "Geo-Res": 67,
                  "Taxi-Only-Route": false
               }
            },
            {
               "Ctg-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": {
                     "c4_route": 202212,
                     "c4_indx": 1,
                     "c4_rwy": "Edw Rwy 04R (500ft)",
                     "c4_routeNum": 88,
                     "c4_wptNum": 547
                  },
                  "Hash": -1807252220
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "210935": {
         "3843146": [
            {
               "Geo-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": 439,
                  "Pri-Wpt-Indx": 21,
                  "Validation-Status": "Validated",
                  "Geo-Res": 67,
                  "Taxi-Only-Route": false
               }
            },
            {
               "Ctg-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": {
                     "c4_route": 211032,
                     "c4_indx": 1,
                     "c4_rwy": "Edw Rwy 04R (500ft)",
                     "c4_routeNum": 105,
                     "c4_wptNum": 969
                  },
                  "Hash": -1807243400
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "216948": {
         "3954104": [
            {
               "Geo-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": 276,
                  "Pri-Wpt-Indx": 21,
                  "Validation-Status": "Validated",
                  "Geo-Res": 67,
                  "Taxi-Only-Route": false
               }
            },
            {
               "Ctg-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": {
                     "c4_route": 187761,
                     "c4_indx": 1,
                     "c4_rwy": "Edw Rwy 04R (500ft)",
                     "c4_routeNum": 104,
                     "c4_wptNum": 989
                  },
                  "Hash": -1807266671
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "216980": {
         "3955100": [
            {
               "Geo-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": 2333,
                  "Pri-Wpt-Indx": 31,
                  "Validation-Status": "Validated",
                  "Geo-Res": 67,
                  "Taxi-Only-Route": false
               }
            },
            {
               "Ctg-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": {
                     "c4_route": 187761,
                     "c4_indx": 1,
                     "c4_rwy": "Edw Rwy 04R (500ft)",
                     "c4_routeNum": 104,
                     "c4_wptNum": 989
                  },
                  "Hash": -1807266671
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "222550": {
         "4080129": [
            {
               "Geo-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": 463,
                  "Pri-Wpt-Indx": 21,
                  "Validation-Status": "Validated",
                  "Geo-Res": 67,
                  "Taxi-Only-Route": false
               }
            },
            {
               "Ctg-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": {
                     "c4_route": 187761,
                     "c4_indx": 1,
                     "c4_rwy": "Edw Rwy 04R (500ft)",
                     "c4_routeNum": 95,
                     "c4_wptNum": 942
                  },
                  "Hash": -1807266671
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "223547": {
         "4106665": [
            {
               "Geo-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": 267,
                  "Pri-Wpt-Indx": 21,
                  "Validation-Status": "Validated",
                  "Geo-Res": 67,
                  "Taxi-Only-Route": false
               }
            },
            {
               "Ctg-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": {
                     "c4_route": 187761,
                     "c4_indx": 1,
                     "c4_rwy": "Edw Rwy 04R (500ft)",
                     "c4_routeNum": 110,
                     "c4_wptNum": 2173
                  },
                  "Hash": -1807266671
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "224012": {
         "4119553": [
            {
               "Geo-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": 221,
                  "Pri-Wpt-Indx": 21,
                  "Validation-Status": "Validated",
                  "Geo-Res": 67,
                  "Taxi-Only-Route": false
               }
            },
            {
               "Ctg-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": {
                     "c4_route": 187761,
                     "c4_indx": 1,
                     "c4_rwy": "Edw Rwy 04R (500ft)",
                     "c4_routeNum": 107,
                     "c4_wptNum": 673
                  },
                  "Hash": -1807266671
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "227030": {
         "4173956": [
            {
               "Geo-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": 567,
                  "Pri-Wpt-Indx": 21,
                  "Validation-Status": "Validated",
                  "Geo-Res": 67,
                  "Taxi-Only-Route": false
               }
            },
            {
               "Ctg-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": {
                     "c4_route": 211032,
                     "c4_indx": 1,
                     "c4_rwy": "Edw Rwy 04R (500ft)",
                     "c4_routeNum": 158,
                     "c4_wptNum": 998
                  },
                  "Hash": -1807243400
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "261957": {
         "4779815": [
            {
               "Geo-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": 276,
                  "Pri-Wpt-Indx": 21,
                  "Validation-Status": "Validated",
                  "Geo-Res": 67,
                  "Taxi-Only-Route": false
               }
            },
            {
               "Ctg-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": {
                     "c4_route": 187761,
                     "c4_indx": 1,
                     "c4_rwy": "Edw Rwy 04R (500ft)",
                     "c4_routeNum": 108,
                     "c4_wptNum": 989
                  },
                  "Hash": -1807266671
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "265659": {
         "4857160": [
            {
               "Geo-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": 463,
                  "Pri-Wpt-Indx": 21,
                  "Validation-Status": "Validated",
                  "Geo-Res": 67,
                  "Taxi-Only-Route": false
               }
            },
            {
               "Ctg-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": {
                     "c4_route": 187761,
                     "c4_indx": 1,
                     "c4_rwy": "Edw Rwy 04R (500ft)",
                     "c4_routeNum": 95,
                     "c4_wptNum": 942
                  },
                  "Hash": -1807266671
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "265767": {
         "4860626": [
            {
               "Geo-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": 463,
                  "Pri-Wpt-Indx": 21,
                  "Validation-Status": "Validated",
                  "Geo-Res": 67,
                  "Taxi-Only-Route": false
               }
            },
            {
               "Ctg-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": {
                     "c4_route": 187761,
                     "c4_indx": 1,
                     "c4_rwy": "Edw Rwy 04R (500ft)",
                     "c4_routeNum": 95,
                     "c4_wptNum": 942
                  },
                  "Hash": -1807266671
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "267100": {
         "4897273": [
            {
               "Geo-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": 242,
                  "Pri-Wpt-Indx": 21,
                  "Validation-Status": "Validated",
                  "Geo-Res": 67,
                  "Taxi-Only-Route": false
               }
            },
            {
               "Ctg-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": {
                     "c4_route": 187761,
                     "c4_indx": 1,
                     "c4_rwy": "Edw Rwy 04R (500ft)",
                     "c4_routeNum": 93,
                     "c4_wptNum": 584
                  },
                  "Hash": -1807266671
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "272778": {
         "5014510": [
            {
               "Geo-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": 2333,
                  "Pri-Wpt-Indx": 31,
                  "Validation-Status": "Validated",
                  "Geo-Res": 67,
                  "Taxi-Only-Route": false
               }
            },
            {
               "Ctg-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": {
                     "c4_route": 272848,
                     "c4_indx": 1,
                     "c4_rwy": "Edw Rwy 04R (500ft)",
                     "c4_routeNum": 108,
                     "c4_wptNum": 989
                  },
                  "Hash": -1807181584
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "274636": {
         "5052398": [
            {
               "Geo-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": 1966,
                  "Pri-Wpt-Indx": 31,
                  "Validation-Status": "Validated",
                  "Geo-Res": 67,
                  "Taxi-Only-Route": false
               }
            },
            {
               "Ctg-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": {
                     "c4_route": 272848,
                     "c4_indx": 1,
                     "c4_rwy": "Edw Rwy 04R (500ft)",
                     "c4_routeNum": 95,
                     "c4_wptNum": 942
                  },
                  "Hash": -1807181584
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "281480": {
         "5207980": [
            {
               "Geo-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": 2902,
                  "Pri-Wpt-Indx": 31,
                  "Validation-Status": "Validated",
                  "Geo-Res": 67,
                  "Taxi-Only-Route": false
               }
            },
            {
               "Ctg-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": {
                     "c4_route": 187761,
                     "c4_indx": 1,
                     "c4_rwy": "Edw Rwy 04R (500ft)",
                     "c4_routeNum": 93,
                     "c4_wptNum": 584
                  },
                  "Hash": -1807266671
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "293448": {
         "5438565": [
            {
               "Geo-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": 2902,
                  "Pri-Wpt-Indx": 31,
                  "Validation-Status": "Validated",
                  "Geo-Res": 67,
                  "Taxi-Only-Route": false
               }
            },
            {
               "Ctg-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": {
                     "c4_route": 187761,
                     "c4_indx": 1,
                     "c4_rwy": "Edw Rwy 04R (500ft)",
                     "c4_routeNum": 93,
                     "c4_wptNum": 584
                  },
                  "Hash": -1807266671
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "307779": {
         "5712719": [
            {
               "Geo-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": 5299,
                  "Pri-Wpt-Indx": 31,
                  "Validation-Status": "Validated",
                  "Geo-Res": 67,
                  "Taxi-Only-Route": false
               }
            },
            {
               "Ctg-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": {
                     "c4_route": 187761,
                     "c4_indx": 1,
                     "c4_rwy": "Edw Rwy 04R (500ft)",
                     "c4_routeNum": 123,
                     "c4_wptNum": 584
                  },
                  "Hash": -1807266671
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "308328": {
         "5728003": [
            {
               "Geo-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": 5299,
                  "Pri-Wpt-Indx": 31,
                  "Validation-Status": "Validated",
                  "Geo-Res": 67,
                  "Taxi-Only-Route": false
               }
            },
            {
               "Ctg-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": {
                     "c4_route": 187761,
                     "c4_indx": 1,
                     "c4_rwy": "Edw Rwy 04R (500ft)",
                     "c4_routeNum": 123,
                     "c4_wptNum": 584
                  },
                  "Hash": -1807266671
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "311708": {
         "5809765": [
            {
               "Geo-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": 276,
                  "Pri-Wpt-Indx": 21,
                  "Validation-Status": "Validated",
                  "Geo-Res": 67,
                  "Taxi-Only-Route": false
               }
            },
            {
               "Ctg-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": {
                     "c4_route": 311810,
                     "c4_indx": 1,
                     "c4_rwy": "Edw Rwy 04R (500ft)",
                     "c4_routeNum": 108,
                     "c4_wptNum": 989
                  },
                  "Hash": -1807142622
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "311740": {
         "5810843": [
            {
               "Geo-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": 2333,
                  "Pri-Wpt-Indx": 31,
                  "Validation-Status": "Validated",
                  "Geo-Res": 67,
                  "Taxi-Only-Route": false
               }
            },
            {
               "Ctg-Details": {
                  "Pri-Wpt": {
                     "c4_route": 311810,
                     "c4_indx": 1,
                     "c4_rwy": "Edw Rwy 04R (500ft)",
                     "c4_routeNum": 108,
                     "c4_wptNum": 989
                  },
                  "Hash": -1807142622
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "Hashed-String": "Wpt[lat=34.843213,lon=-118.005453,alt=NoReq,vel=NoReq,tu=NoReq,ty=4],Wpt[lat=34.852209,lon=-117.987876,alt=4500,vel=NoReq,tu=NoReq,ty=5],Wpt[lat=34.89528,lon=-117.903598,alt=2100,vel=NoReq,tu=0,ty=5],Wpt[lat=34.904633,lon=-117.885272,alt=NoReq,vel=6,tu=NoReq,ty=2],",
   "Hash": "0b464306360ee6b04199069824614b2f"
}
```

And what I am wondering if there exists either a Node.JS module, or a pure Javascript module that can take in a JSON object and output the HTML which will allow the JSON to be clickable (so I can drill into the levels), and perhaps allow me to reduce the data (note how the Detail level hash has a lot of redundancy.

At the very least, it would be a function which I can feed in a JSON object (or a stringified JSON) and output would be the proper HTML & CSS which supports it. Even cooler would be if I could fill in more arguments that would help reduce the data a bit.

I figure something like this has to be created already, but my Google searches aren't good enough to find the right one!

Comment: One of these three tools will probably help you: http://stedolan.github.io/jq/ — https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc?hl=en — http://jsonview.com/

Answer (score 2):

There sure is. It's called [Dynatable](http://www.dynatable.com/#existing-json). It's a "HTML5+JSON interactive table plugin". I apologize for just posting a link, but it is a 3rd-party module as you requested.

> Once we have our JSON dataset, we can perform all our interactive and
>   dynamic logic directly on the JSON using JavaScript. By default,
>   dynatable comes with functions for sorting, filtering (aka searching),
>   and paginating. ... The results of the Operate step are rendered back
>   to the DOM in the body of the table.

Comment: A more specific link that leads directly to information relevant to the question is http://www.dynatable.com/#existing-json

Comment: I'm messing with dynatable and it seems promising. I am trying to feed it that exact JSON object but it doesn't seem to take. Should I be expected to clean up the JSON first?

Comment: Hmm, dynatable doesn't give a lot of debug statements, but I think my JSON object won't work since it doesn't look like an array? I'm not sure but my `obj.Details` part of the JSON is what I'd expect to be easily parseable into a table but it isn't doing anything.